# Java on easypeasy

Tags: java

I have successfully installed easypeasy in an Asus EeePC. I want to use the authoring programm Hot Potatoes, which is/uses a Java application (sorry for my poor technical vocabulary). It is installed and extracted. I have found guidelines about how to use it [here](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/installationsanleitung-fuer-hot-potatoes/) (it is in German but the instructions for the terminal are clear).

But it seems I cannot install any Java package. I have tried all the packages the terminal says are available and this is what terminal says: "Unable to find the package".

In ubuntu I use Hot Potatoes with wine, but I cannot install it in the Asus, so I need to run it with java.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this PPA version from webupd8

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Source - [HERE](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)

Comment: It worked!!!! Thanks a lot. I hope it is right to express it within a comment.

Comment: Click accept and you are welcome